# What is the fastest way to compare the minimum right most characters between two fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a phone number field in two different tables. I want to compare the right most characters of both for the minimum length. Is one way more efficient than another to do this in PostgreSQL?

Here's some pseudo-code to better describe the question:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contacts c
JOIN Users u
ON compareFromRight( c.phone, u.phone, LEAST( length( c.phone ), length( u.phone ) ) );
```

I have a 7 digit index that I used to reduce things, but then once I get to that small set I need to compare as much of the two raw numbers as I have. The minimum comparable length will be different from row to row.

Thanks.

Here's another example that I imagine would NOT perform well:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Contacts c
JOIN Users u ON RIGHT( c.phone, LEAST( LENGTH( c.phone ), LENGTH( u.phone ) ) ) 
   = RIGHT( u.phone, LEAST( LENGTH( c.phone ), LENGTH( u.phone ) ) )
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Not sure I understand, two tables each with a string field. I want to compare the fields from the right for the minimum length between the two strings. Just like the SQL above. So if I have two string "Hello World" and "World" they will compare as true but "Hello World" and "a World" would not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT  c.Phone AS ContactPhone, u.Phone AS UserPhone
FROM    Contacts c
        JOIN Users u
            ON u.phone LIKE '%' || c.Phone
            OR c.Phone LIKE '%' || u.Phone;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7274b/3)**

While probably more efficient than what is in the question, it is still unlikely to perform well on a large set of data.

Comment: Thanks! This is great, do you really think it is likely to perform better than RIGHT(c.phone, LEAST(LENGTH(c.phone), LENGTH(u.phone))) 
   = RIGHT(u.phone, LEAST(LENGTH(c.phone), LENGTH(u.phone)))? I'll try both out and benchmark and report back.

Comment: The SQL plan is less with your approach.

Comment: You could create a computed index on the reverse of the strings then use LIKE u.phone || '%' which would most likely be faster.

Comment: To be honest I don't think there will be much difference, the cost is slightly less on the nested loop join, but I don't think either approach is staggeringly fast. The suggestion by @LoztInSpace could be the best option.

Comment: Still [doesn't appear to be much difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8ece4/1). It might be different on your data though as I am only using a small sample.

Comment: I think it will be okay because I will only do this for records that already match on a 7 digit sample that is indexed as an integer. So basically like this: "c.significant = u.significant AND (c.phone LIKE u.phone OR u.phone LIKE c.phone)". Btw, sorry to show my ignorance but what does "'%' ||" buy me?

Comment: Paraphrased from the [Postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/indexes-types.html) -- When you use pattern matching from the start the optimiser can make use of indexes (e.g. `col LIKE 'foo%'`), but cannot use an index if you pattern match from the end (e.g. `col LIKE 'foo%'`). So reversing the string allows you to pattern match from the start and use the index.

Comment: But wont LIKE without the '%' work here since it only matches if one string is a complete substring of the other? Maybe even being faster?

Comment: No, because one is still like the other, using your example you still need `'Hello World' LIKE '%World'`, reversing it simply changes it to `dlroW olleH` LIKE 'dlroW%'`, meaning the index can be used.

Comment: Not to drag this on too long but I could also pretty easily store these particular strings reversed and then just reverse them again for display. They only need to be fast for correlation, a reverse on each to display is not a big deal they aren't in any long ass reports.